# Efficient way of matching array with one to one relationship

Tags: node.js, ecmascript-6

If in node we have 2 arrays of objects with one to one relationship and we want to match them efficiently is there some function/s to do the following on cleaner way?

```
var users = [{id:1},{id:2}]
var userDetails =[{userId:1, eyeColor:'red'},{userId:2, eyeColor:'blue'}]

users.map((u)=>{
    userDetails.find((detail,index)=>{
        return u.id == u.userId ? u.eyeColor = userDetails.splice(index, 1)[0] : false;
    })
})
```

Answer (score 1):

I think your code has been simplified enough. Alternatively you can use filter

```
var filteredArray  = users.filter(function(first){
   return userDetails.filter(function(second){
      return first.id == second.userId;
   });
});
```

or you can take a look at `lodash` library for more simplified way

Comment: this code you posted would go trough full starting array userDetails for each consecutive  user making it highly inefficient for large arrays. if we know there is one to one relationship between arrays we can shorten the search by splicing the userDetails array making search for each consecutive user shorter. Thats why i wrote efficient :)

Comment: I thought like that too and thanks to the js library too. If not we may end out using the traditional way of nested loop to find the matching record.

Comment: we should write a petition :)